# Trying to send cookies from node.js backend to next.js frontend. Used to implement signup with google and set jwt in cookies of frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, cookies, cors

I am using node.js for backend and next.js for frontend. I am implementing signup with google and if it succeeds than backend will generate JWT. This token must be stored in frontend and used for authentication for later use.

Google strategy passport setup

```
passport.use(new googleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL:"https://xyz.vercel.app/auth/google/callback",
    scope: ['profile', 'email'],
  }, async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    try {
      // Check if a user with the Google ID exists in your database
      let user = await User.findOne({ where:{googleId: profile.id }});
  
      if (!user) {
        // Create a new user with Google ID
        user = new User({
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            role: 'user',
            googleId: profile.id
        });
        console.log(user)
        const newuser = await user.save();
        console.log('newuser' + newuser)
      }
      console.log(user)
      return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return done(err);
    }
  }));
```

```
router.get(
    "/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "email"],
    })
);

router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        session: false,
    }),
    function (req, res) {
        const token = generateJWTToken(req.user);
        console.log(token);

        res.cookie("access_token", token, {
            sameSite: "Lax",
            httpOnly: true,
        })
        res.setHeader("access_token", token);
        res.redirect("https://frontend.vercel.app/success"); // frontend url
    }
);
```

I am trying to set cookie in the frontend but it is not getting set. Cookie can be seen at the intermediate url which is generated by Google. `https://xyz.vercel.app/auth/google/callback?code=4%2F0AfJohXnO83moTRc0agDzdWmhJ98OnF6iGSEqc3vfG3tP3d3PDJx0rjbh44X2aI3AUA&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&hd=daiict.ac.in&prompt=none`. The cookie has to be set in /success url.

How to write the code to complete setting this cookie in frontend.